# Как на angular обработать шаблон в момент получения ajax ответа?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

В html файле есть метки для вывода информации:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
    <span class="blc" ng-repeat="process in processess">
    <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle"></i>
    <span class="p-left ">{{ process.caption }}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Что делать, подскажите, как правильно обрабатывать ng-repeat при обработке ajax-ом?

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 

/*
если оставить так, то данные выведутся, ибо они уже присутствуют при загрузке страницы
$scope.processess = [
 {caption: "ОПИСАНИЕ_1"},
 {caption: "ОПИСАНИЕ_2"}
];

*/

// однако, данные лежат в базе, и я их вытаскиваю через jquery.ajax + custom
service.processtypes().then(function(data){
    // $scope.processess не отрабатывает и не отображается на странице
    $scope.processess = [
     {caption: data[0]},
     {caption: data[1]}
    ];

});


}]);
```

Что делать, подскажите, как правильно обрабатывать ng-repeat при обработке ajax-ом?

Comment: вот так и сделать - это обычная практика - когда придет ответ, view перерисуется, хотя это зависит от содержания `service.processtypes`

Comment: добавь пример содержания `service.processtypes`

Comment: добавьте $scope.$digest() после $scope.processess, чтобы запустить digest цикл ангуляра

Comment: добавь внутри функции console.log(data), что бы понять что там за данные.

Comment: $scope.$digest() - помог

Comment: стоит разобраться когда и зачем стоит применять данные методы, лучше вместо `jquery.ajax` использовать `$http` - он сделает все что нужно автоматически

Comment: @Grundy совершенно справедливое замечание. Нужно избегать использования $digest и уж тем более $apply

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести JSON данные из angular scope?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691266/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-json-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-angular-scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если длина массива data непостоянная, то лучше делать так.

```
service.processtypes().then(function(data){
    $scope.processess = data.map(function(item){
         return {"caption":item};
    });
});
```

а в html попробуй сделать так, тогда возможно избавишься от $apply

```
<span class="blc" ng-repeat="process in processess track by $index">
```

Comment: а смысл делать так? тем более тут лучше использовать метод `map`, который как раз и предназначен для получения нового массива на основе исходного

Comment: про map не знал, спасибо, исправил. А смысл очевиден.

Comment: вообще от $apply способом из ответа не избавиться. Потому что проблема не в массива, а в _service.processtypes_

Comment: я подумал, что нет смысла делать map. Про trak by $index это так предположение.

Comment: ну я про тот forEach и говорил, потому что сначала не понял зачем он :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$apply();
```

метод очень помог

Comment: лучше $digest, цикл будет короче, если только $scope.processess не появляются где-то выше

Answer (score 0):

Так как

> вытаскиваю через jquery.ajax + custom

Ангуляр не знает, что запрос закончился, данные обновились и нужно обновить соответствующее view.

Вариантов решения множество: вызов [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest), обернуть в функцию [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), воспользоваться сервисом [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Но **лучшее** решение - воспользоваться встроенным сервисом [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) для запросов, при получении ответа, ангуляр сам проделает необходимые действия и обновит view если потребуется.