# не работает select2, angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Привет. Использую angular 1.5 и плагинчик select2 во вьюшке

```
<select2 id="group_triggers" ng-model="groups" s2-options="group.id as group.title for group in groups">
</select>
```

в groups у меня аяксом подгружается Объект объектов.
Опытным путем установил что select2 нормально работает когда в scope массив объектов. А что делать когда Объект объектов я не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста

```
var data_triggers = 0;
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/admin/triggers/tab_digests_show',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        data_triggers = data.response;
    }
});
```

```
reports_admin.controller(
    'triggers',
    function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.groups = data_triggers.group_triggers;
    console.log($scope.groups);
```

Comment: _в groups у меня аяксом подгружается Объект объектов._ - покажи как именно? если вставить именно этот _Объект объектов_ - все заработает?

Comment: подкрепил картинку, как раз таки нет вот с обьектом Обьектов не работает

Comment: нужен текст. код подгрузки, и пример объекта. На картинке не известно что выведено: массив или объект. А от этого может зависеть способ решения

Comment: добавил код в пример

Comment: У меня два варианта какими вопросами закрыть как дубликат: 1. [получение значения из функции обратного вызова](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/186999) и 2. [ангуляр не обновляет view при запросе $.ajax](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/544095/186999)

Comment: когда выполняется указанный ajax запрос?

Comment: спасибо, ознакомлюсь

Comment: Закрыл как дубликаты, если ни один из ответов не поможет, отредактируй свой вопрос, добавив больше информации, например: [mcve], пример данных которые ты получаешь и т.д.