# Своевременный обмен данных между кнотроллер-сервис-директива

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-directive

Код директивы. В ней выводятся данные с сервиса

```
angular.module('navigation.frameNavBottom', [])
    .directive('frameNavBottom', ['frameDataStorage', function(frameDataStorage) {
        return {
            template: require('./templates/index.html'),
            link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller, $translate) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    /*service frameDataStorage*/
                    $scope.providerInfo = frameDataStorage.getProviderInfo();
                    /*end service frameDataStorage*/
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
    }

]);

module.exports = 'navigation.frameNavBottom';
```

код сервиса

```
angular.module('frame-data-storage', [])
    .service('frameDataStorage', frameDataStorage);

frameDataStorage.$inject = [];

function frameDataStorage() {
    var _logo = '',
        _category = '',
        _pinfo = '';
    return {
        setLogo: function (logo) {
            _logo = logo;
        },
        setCat: function (category) {
            _category = category;
        },
        setProviderInfo: function (pinfo) {
            _pinfo = pinfo;
        },
        getLogo: function () {
            return _logo;
        },
        getCat: function () {
            return _category;
        },
        getProviderInfo: function () {
            return _pinfo;
        }
    }
}
```

кусок контроллера где мы передаем данные в сервис

```
 $q.all(
        [
            PortalApi.searchServices({
                query: $stateParams.serviceId,
                limit: 1,
                location: 0,
                sortByPayments: false
            }),
            PortalApi.getService($stateParams.serviceId),
            ClientCards.getList()
        ]
    ).then(function(resolve) {

        $scope.searchServices = resolve[0][0] || {}; // search


        /*'service' page. footer info from service.provide_info*/
        $scope.providerInfo = $scope.getService.service.provider_info;
        /*end 'service' page. footer info from service.provide_info*/

        /*data to service*/
        console.log('godata');//TODO: delete
            frameDataStorage.setLogo($scope.searchServices.icon);
            frameDataStorage.setCat($scope.categoryName);
            frameDataStorage.setProviderInfo($scope.providerInfo);
        /*end data to service*/
```

В шаблоне выводиться все просто {{scope}}
Проблема в том что при загрузки страници, данные которые через сервис должны выводиться, не выводятся при первой загрузке страници. Срабатывают только при повторной загрузке страници(перезагрузке).

Возможно есть другие варианты вывода данных. В шапку и Футер пытаюсь передать эти данные с контролера.

Comment: ох-ох-ох... посмотри ответ на вопрос: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/186999) если разберешься, закрою как дубликат

Comment: или возможно этот вопрос может помочь: [Как на angular обработать шаблон в момент получения ajax ответа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/544039/186999)

Comment: спасибо. пока что отставил сервис и использую rootscope но это из ряда "очень плохо". буду дальше розбиратся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло

> $scope.$watch

```
angular.module('navigation.frameNavBottom', [])
    .directive('frameNavBottom', ['frameDataStorage','$timeout', function(frameDataStorage,$timeout) {
        return {
            template: require('./templates/index.html'),
            link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller, $translate) {
                $scope.$watch(function(){
                    /*service frameDataStorage*/
                    $scope.providerInfo = frameDataStorage.getProviderInfo();
                    /*end service frameDataStorage*/
                });
            }
        }
    }

]);
```