# Как вывести JSON данные из angular scope?

Tags: json, angularjs

Есть два контроллера:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $.get('http://localhost:5000/Nop.Web/auction/GetJsonDataByExtId?ExtId=' + ExtId, function (data) {
        $scope.carsname = data[0].Name;
        console.log('JSON GOT IT: ' + data[0].Name);
    });
});
app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope) {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/Nop.Web/auction/GetJsonData', function (data) {
        console.log('List of objects: ' + data);
    });
});
```

И разметка:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Angular got it: {{carsname}}</h1>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col col-md-12" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
                    <ul class="bxslider3">

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Первый получает один JSON объект, второй - набор JSON объектов.

Требуется чтобы первый выводил `data[0].Name`, а второй выводил лист объектов `data[i].Name`

Comment: @Grundy там галочка на неправильном ответе стоит...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это да, но я по своему ответу ориентировался :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывод массивов в шаблонах angular осуществляется с помощью директивы [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Выглядеть это будет так.

Контроллер:

```
app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:5000/Nop.Web/auction/GetJsonData'}).then(function (data) {
        console.log('List of objects: ' + data);
        $scope.data = data; // Переменная data должна быть массивом!
    });
});
```

Шаблон:

```
<div class="col col-md-12" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
    <ul class="bxslider3">
        <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.Name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

PS в angular есть [средства для отправки запросов](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Вам не нужен тут jQuery.

Comment: В качестве средства отправки запросов, лучше использовать ``$resource``, а не ``$http``

Comment: ваш пример не работает

Comment: @a.tarasevich Какая ошибка выводится?

Comment: @IgorGolovin в $scope.data ничего не приходит

Comment: @a.tarasevich используйте $http или $resource как писали выше. Обновил ответ

Comment: @IgorGolovin да, так возможно заработает. Не проверял, но поверю на слово. Так как сделал через такой же метод, но немного иначе. Приму ваш ответ. Спасибо!